# Using state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I'm using this state machine to manage a "state" attribute on an Invite object

https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

I want to have a send_invite method the sets the state to "sending", sends the invite , and then sets the state to "sent" or to "could_not_send" is there is some error

It seems like I should be able to do that in the state machine DSL , am I wrong ?

Or should I just add a normal method?

```
   state_machine :initial => :pending do
        event :send do
          transition :pending => :sending
        end

        event :invite_sent do
          transition :sending => :invited
        end

        event :error_sending do
          transition :sending => :error
        end    
    end

    def send_invite
       send
       try 
         .... code to send invite...
         invite_sent
       catch
          error_sending!
       end 
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

State machine was built to provide virtual 'states' over a series of stateless web requests.  Since you are doing this all in one request, it's not really necessary to use something this heavy - but it should work if you prefer to use it.